# How to determine the value of the variable resistor to land on saturation region?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistors, dc, linear

I'm trying to determine the  **Linear region** of the transistor by setting an upper and lower limit for the resistor on the lower left hand corner. I've already fixed the lower limit and tried to find a value for upper limit by using: $$I_B+I_C=I_E$$
$$R_EI_E+R_CI_C = 15$$ $$\frac{15R_2}{R_2+10^5}-B_{BE} - I_ER_E =0$$  Clearly these set of equations ain't enough. Is there any way out ? or i'm fundamentally wrong?  [image]

Comment: You're forgetting \$V_{CE}\$, and that \$0.7\$ is usually denoted as \$V_{BE}\$

Comment: @HarrySvensson I should i'v mentioned it, indeed $$V_CE$$ is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### added

Another explicit method is choose Vc= 15/2 then add Ve= 1.5 and add 0.5V for saturation margin at low current.

Thus Vc=8V and Ic= (15-8)V/2.21k=3.17mA and Ve=3.17m*221R = 700mV and thus Vb=1.4V from which you can compute R2 = 10.3k and raising R2 to compensate for the Re loading effect on input impedance at base.

Using hFE=100 we get Zin=100*221R = 22k //R2= 10.3k or (1/22)-(1/10.3)=1/R2
Thus **R2 = 19.3k** //22k(Zin) = 10.3k for Vb=1.4V, Vc=8V, Ve=0.7V and 14Vpp swing max with 1.4Vpp in.

(final answer)

[image]
 For an ideal transistor say with the current gain at 100, and an H biased voltage amplifier with a gain of 10 you expect The resistors to drop 10+1 times the emitter resistor V(Re), value in voltage to match Vcc=15V with Vce=0. Then if we assume Vbe=0.7V we can choose Vb for linear symmetry.

We expect 15V supply with an AC gain of 10 will lose some range for Re thus a good bias point for R2 results in a t least a 13Vpp swing with a gain of 10 for an input of 1.3Vpp . So intuitively you can say Vb must be 0.7{Vbe}+1.3V/2 or about 1.4V thus R2 will be just under 10% of 100k.

This is how we do it on our heads in about a minute after years of practice and success.

But poking on this iPod takes forever!

Vb >1/(1+Av)*Vcc+Vbe = R2/(R1+R2)*Vcc.

So we want Vb such that Vce=0 but Vc will achieve a full swing on both peaks at the same amplitude for a gain of 10.

The following would DC bias Vce into saturation but you would not want this for full AC voltage swing, rather you want Vc to be mid range between Vcc and Ve.

15V/11+0.7=1.1V =R2/(100k+R2)*15V.
or  inverting both sides.
100k/R2 +1  = 15V/1.1=13.6 =12.6+1
So R2=100k/12.6 = 8k approx.

The equations can easily be simplified by you to be a function of Rc/Re=Av and Vcc.

advanced
—

In reality hFE drops rapidly to 10% max with Vce starting at Vce<=1V for low current and 2V for high current so we avoid Vce<2 for good linearity in sine waves such that Vp+=|Vp-| <<1% for low distortion.

Answer (score 0):

To set a hard upper limit consider that with the thing starting to saturate Vce will be small so you can figure the current in the chain (ignoring the drop in beta near saturation) as 15/(Rc+Re) near enough which I make to be right on about 6mA, 6mA in Re will develop 1.36V across it, so Vb(max) is just a nads over 2V, figure the divider ratio appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. Just use the relations that implies the transistor parameters:

$$
I_C = \alpha I_E
$$

Therefor you can calculate the approximation of the emitter's current in saturation mode:

$$
R_E I_E + R_C \alpha I_E = 15
$$

And apply the result to the voltage divider:

$$
\dfrac{15 R_2}{R_2+10^5} −0.7−I_E R_E=0
$$

Comment: And how i can find $$I_E$$ ?

Comment: If you have the parameter alpha, it is the only unknown in the second equation. If you have the beta, you can calculate it with $\alpha = \dfrac{ \beta }{ \beta + 1}$

Comment: Unfortunately and don't have neither of 'em!

Comment: Where did you got that schematic or problem? You can't calculate anything with transistor if you don't have data from them... It is like if you are trying to calculate a current through a resistor and you don't know the resistance. Then, the unique possibility would be to make a supposition about something that would probably lead to errors on some circuits.

Comment: As far as remember, the linear region in this configuration is independent of alpha and beta.

Comment: That configuration makes the amplifier independent from temperature variations, DC mean value of signals, etc... But when calculating the biasing point of a transistor, it can't be independent: the greater the beta parameter of a BJT, more easy to saturate on that configuration.

Comment: The unique way of doing so, would be to assume that the beta is enough big to say that there is no difference between Ie and Ic, then Ic equals Ie and you can solve the second equation without alpha. But again, it cannot be independent, we are just making an “enough big” supposition.

Comment: Actually i meant I_C in DC is independent of beta. It sounds wired to me thats why i i'm asking it here. Clearly we can only make assumptions, thanks.

Comment: Modern small signal NPN transistor beta is usually in the 100-500 or so region and is not in any case remotely well controlled over temperature or process variations. Given that 100 is a reasonably large number, you can assume that the base current is small compared to the emitter current and thus that Ic ~= Ie to within a percent or so in the linear region. Note that this assumption of a small base current should also be designed to hold for the bias network, but sometimes does not.